# Duplicate screen AND use CEC on both HDMI ports (RPi 4)

Tags: hdmi, cec-client

I use a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian 11 (bullseye).
I want to duplicate the screen on both HDMI ports AND use CEC protocol to switch on/off the TVs.

However, with `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d` I manage to duplicate the screen, but CEC only works on first port.

With `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d`, I can use CEC on both ports, but I could get video output on both ports.

How to use at the same time screen mirroring and CEC ?